# Windows 10 Do you want to run this file prompt

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code, security-warning

I am using Visual Studio code from the zip file so that I have more control of where my data is stored (trying to keep it from writing to my roaming profile), but every time that I launch the application Windows 10 is giving me a security warning asking if I want to run the file, is there a way to disable this warning for this specific file? Note, that I do not want to disable this for all files.

[image: Visual Studio Code Security Warning]

Comment: Please provide the information from the Security tab on the properties of the file in question.  You can also ask your IT Administrator to adjust the settings on your system to trust the file in question  I am going to guess, the file location is a network location instead of an internal drive.

Comment: The file location is on a local drive and I should be able to adjust settings on that drive as needed, but don't know how to trust the file.

Comment: I know you don't know how to trust the file, which is the reason, I asked you for screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this security warning *precisely because you are running it straight from the zip archive.* You're essentially running vscode from the temp directory.

This warning shows up for all executables ran from the temp directory as well as network shares. Disabling for just this file is *possible* but since you run your file straight from the zip archive I'd be surprised if Windows remembers this setting. To do this, simply navigate to the .exe in your temp folder, go to its file properties and check the "unblock" checkbox.

**However** since you're trying to "sandbox" your vscode installation, I'd recommend checking out [VSCode's Portable Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) instead. This mode enables all data created and maintained by VS Code to live near itself, so it can be moved around across environments. It will essentially write everything to its own data folder rather than your roaming profile.

Comment: I actually am trying to use the portable mode, but may not have dome something properly. I extracted the zip file to my secondary hard drive and have a custom data and extensions folder as it instructs to use.